# How to send data to the TemplateView used in openpyxl to generate xlsx files in DJango

Tags: python, django, excel

I have downloaded `xlsx` files before by using this library, and it's amazing, but now I want to send data to use it in a queryset to fill the `xlsx` sheet.

I have a submit button that uses jquery to prevent default and according to a checkbox it either sends the data through Ajax to a View that stores the data in the database, or send it to a file, but I don't know how to send the data to the view which process `openpyxl` and download the file at the same time. I have tried by calling the TemplateView through Ajax, I know how to send data through Get method by using Ajax, and how to recieve the data in the overrided GET method in the `TemplateView`, but when I try that, the file just doesn't downloads. According to the tutorial that I was following, I have to use an `<a>` tag and call the `TemplateView` by using: `href="{% url 'download_the_file' %}"`.

So my question is, how can I send data to that TemplateView and download the file, knowing that I need to use Jquery to activate the sending data process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The people that gave me -2 probably was thinking this was a simple excel problem.

I found a solution, in my jquery function I added this:

```
$(location).attr('href', '/the_url?number=5');
```

Without using Ajax, just send the parameter in the URL that is linked to the TemplateView.